# ajax extjs having problems with up/down methods

Tags: ajax, extjs

hey guys so i'm trying to add a simple handler on a button in my window. The handler just sets a value from a text file to a combobox item id = 'wildanimal'

```
  items: [{
    itemId: 'button1',
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'click the button',
         handler: function(){
                         Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: 'stuff.txt',
            method: 'GET',
            success: function (result){
            this.up('Ajax').down('wildAnimal').setValue(result.responseText)
                                                      }
                                         })
                                     }
```

however I receive a Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'up' ... is there a way to do this without using .up ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will probably solve your problem.  Your 'this' reference is to the ajax function and not to the button like you are expecting:

```
items: [{
    itemId: 'button1',
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'click the button',
         handler: function(theButton){
            Ext.Ajax.request({
                url: 'stuff.txt',
                method: 'GET',
                success: function (result){
                    theButton.up('window').queryById('wildAnimal').setValue(result.responseText)
                }
            });
        }
```